# How to obtain analytical solution for coupled nonlinear differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, nonlinear-system

Following are the two sets of coupled nonlinear differential equations:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{1-x}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{y}{(1-x)^{2}}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}&=AF-\left(A+B\right)\cdot x\\
\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=C-B\cdot(1-x)
\end{align}
$$

where, $x$ and $y$ are dependent variables on independent variable $t$.
$A$, $F$, $B$, and $C$ are constants

at $t=0$, $x=0$, $y=y_{0}$ (Initial condition)

Comment: Please format the mathematical expressions because it is confusing to read in text format

Comment: I have modified the equations, please do have a look

Comment: Next time put your equation between two dollar signs for inline equation or between two double dollar signs for separate equation like in above.

Comment: Sure Sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**...the left-hand side of the first equation is equivalent to $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{xy}{(1-x)^2}\right)$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: The left-hand side of the first equation will take the form of $$d/dt (xy/(1-x))$$ but that doesn't help.

Comment: substitute the $x$ from the second equation into the first, rearrange and integrate, so you will get $y$ in terms of $x$ and $t$